# "as of" in numpy

Tags: python, loops, numpy, time-series

I am looking for a way to implement an "as of" operator in `numpy`. Specifically, if:

1. `t1` is an `n`-vector of timestamps in a strictly increasing order;
2. `d1` is an `n x p` matrix of observations, with `i`-th row corresponding to `t1[i]`;
3. `t2` in an `m`-vector of timestamps, also in a strictly increasing order;

I need to create an `m x p` matrix `d2`, where `d2[i]` is simply `d1[j]` for the largest value of `j` such that `t1[j] <= t2[i]`.

In other words, I need to get the rows of `d1` *as of* the timestamps in `t2`.

It is easy to write this in pure Python, but I am wondering if there's a way to avoid having interpreted loops (`n`, `m` and `p` are quite large).

The timestamps are [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects. The observations are floating-point values.

**edit**:  For entries where `t1[j] <= t2[i]` can't be satisfied (i.e. where a timestamp in `t2` precedes all timestamps in `t1`), I would ideally like to get rows of `NaN`s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best choice is [`numpy.searchsorted()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
d1[numpy.searchsorted(t1, t2, side="right") - 1]
```

This will search the indices where the values of `t2` would have to be inserted into `t1` to maintain order.  The `side="right"` and `- 1` bits are to ensure exactly the specified behaviour.

**Edit**: To get rows of NaNs where the condition `t1[j] <= t2[i]` can't be satisfied, you could use

```
nan_row = numpy.repeat(numpy.nan, d1.shape[1])
d1_nan = numpy.vstack((nan_row, d1))
d2 = d1_nan[numpy.searchsorted(t1, t2, side="right")]
```

Comment: In the ideal world, for entries where `t1[j] <= t2[i]` can't be satisfied, I'd like to get rows of `NaN`s. Thanks again!

Comment: @aix: Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You, sir, are a star. P.S. `vstack` takes a tuple so the code is missing a second pair of parentheses.